# Shell can't resolve argument

Tags: shell, curl, arguments

I am passing arguments to the shell script below **./script.sh pan.tgz 192.168.3.1 ABCXYZ**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $1 $2 $3
file=$1
host=$2
key=$3

curl -kv -o ${file} 'https://${host}/api/?type=export&category=device-state&key=${key}'
```

but getting error **curl: (6) Could not resolve host: $host**

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Advanced Bash scripting guide](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html) states in chapter 5 that inside single quotes, the special meaning of `$` is turned off, hence no variable expansion is performed. You could try enclosing your `curl` argument in double quotes `" ... "` instead of the single quotes.